# Make Jquery apply calculations to one <div> at a time w/o affecting others on page

Tags: jquery, foreach, width

I want look at the total size of a set of columns in a table and then set their width to the average of their widths. Jquery below works great if there's only one table on the page. However, in some cases there will be more than one table on the page. Their widths need to be calculated individually.

```
$('.tableQuestion').each(function(){
  var answerWidth = 0;
  $('table tr:first-child td.radio-answer').each(function(index, elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    answerWidth += $elem.width();
  });
  changeWidth = answerWidth / <?php echo $numColumns; ?>;
  $('table td.radio-answer').width(changeWidth);
});
```

There are multiple `<div class="tableQuestion>` each with a single table within.

Right now, each time through the loop it recalculates the widths for all tables on the page. How can I make it calculate one table at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to apply it to the current context. so change this line:

```
 $('table tr:first-child td.radio-answer').each(function(index, elem) {
```

to

```
$(this).find('tr:first-child td.radio-answer').each(function(index, elem) {
```

and

```
$('table td.radio-answer').width(changeWidth);
```

to

```
$(this).find('td.radio-answer').width(changeWidth);
```